# Can I compile wolfram code into latex like sagemath does with the sagetex package?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, latex

I'm trying to use mathematics inside latex. Just as it is done with sagetex. I have the suspicion that it cannot be done since mathematica is not open source, but hope is the last thing that I'm lost.

If they haven't used sagetex here is an example of how it works.

You compile the latex document.

[image: Latex code]

This is the pdf generated by latex

[image: first Pdf]

Latex generates this auxiliary document (document.sagetex.sage)

[image]

in the sage console I compile the auxiliary document (document.sagetex.sage)

[image]

When compiling the latex document again (From the first image) this is the result

[image]

And when recompiling the latex document now the pdf document gives you the results of the operations.

Basically this computes inside the document and prints the result.

And the ease of this is that general functions and variables can be declared for the whole document.

Is there a similar alternative for wolfram?
Since wolfram has more computing power than sagemath.

thanks!!!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to do? It's a bit unclear what you mean by compile/use

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I recall reading about a single command, which reads any file, and replaces Mathematica expressions with the corresponding output... cant find it at the moment unfortunately, but it seems that this is what you want to run just before compiling your .tex